# Application log level

Tags: c, linux

I've seen a lot of applications with different log levels, where you can enable/disable them with the level number you specify.

For example, log level 1 has the most details and outputs a lot of detail. Level 2 has less details, level 3 is even less detailed, and level 4 is to disable logging altogether.

Can you please advise on how to implement that in a C application?

Answer (score 2):

It all basically comes down to the logging function. It will be something like:

```
#define LOG_ALL       0
#define LOG_DEBUG     1
#define LOG_INFO      2
#define LOG_WARN      3
#define LOG_ERROR     4
#define LOG_FATAL     5
#define LOG_NEXTFREE  6

static unsigned int threshold = LOG_WARN;

void logIt (unsigned int level, char *message) {
    if (level >= threshold)
        puts (message);
}
```

In other words, the log function will only output a message if the level for that message is sufficient to pass the logging threshold. You call it with things like:

```
logIt (LOG_INFO, "process starting");
logIt (LOG_FATAL, "cannot read boot sector");
```

At the default threshold (warning), you will see the latter but not the former.

All you need to add then is a way to modify the threshold dynamically and you can affect what gets logged.

```
void getAndChangeLevel (unsigned int newLevel) {
    if (newLevel < LOG_NEXTFREE)
        threshold = newLevel;
}
```

Of course, there's all sorts of *other* functionality that may be desirable, I've tried to keep the code simple to illustrate the particular concept you asked about.

Comment: How to integrate that with the application, is it just calling the log function all the time and the log function will decide based on the threshold?

Comment: @user1832809, yes, that's exactly it. All your code does is call the function with an indication as to what level this message should be logged. The logging function itself decides if that meets the threshold.